# How to list local directory files from server with Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to list all the video file in  local system. I have used this code to get it.

```
def brows_video_files_from_a_directory
    if params[:file_directory]
        two_dimentional_array = []
        combined = []
        file_directory = params[:file_directory]
        Dir.glob(file_directory + "/*.{mov,mp4,flv,mkv,avi,wmv,mpg,mpeg,3gp}").each.with_index do |item, index|
            @file_details = two_dimentional_array << create_array_of_data(item, combined)
        end
    end
end
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7jIE.png <- Check this screenshot

it works fine in my local system (http://localhost:3000/) but after push to the server it trying to fetch the directory from the server not from the local machine , is there any way to  list all the  files from local machine

Answer (score 0):

The server code is run on the server machine, and your code only allows to read files from a local filesystem.

If you want to read files from a computer different from the server, you need to use a protocol that allows to access the filesystem of a remote computer.

You can make a SSH connection from your server to your local computer, and you will be able to run commands though the SSH connection.

You can also use other protocols, such as FTP, SMB, ...